# View .deb package files in vim

Tags: deb, vim

`vim` is capable of reading compressed files (for common methods, at least). However, it sees Debian package files as binary gibberish. The [Archive Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/file-roller/) tool can, however, open package files and show them like normal archives. What can I do to make `vim` open package files like other archives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the package `vim-scripts` and `vim-addon-manager`, then do `vim-addons install debPlugin`. The second package is solely for `vim-addons`. The relevant file is `/usr/share/vim-scripts/plugin/debPlugin.vim`, which in turn states that it is the [deb.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1970).

Comment: I finally used the plugin directly from the vim plugins site, so I edited your answer to provide that information.